# How to resolve the multiple records using find in Graphql with Mongoose and ES6 promises

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, graphql

I recently started working with Graphql when find multiple records with a condition(like find({'author.id':id})) from the database i am getting the response NULL.In console all records are getting printed, but when resolve the response shows null.

my code like:

```
 export default {
    eventByUserId: {
        type: new GraphQLList(EventType),
        args: {
          id: {
            type: GraphQLID
          }
        },
        resolve: (root, {id}) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Event.find({'author.id': id}).exec((err, res) => {
        console.log(res);
         err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
        });
      });
    };
   }
  };
```

passing Query like:

```
  {
  eventByUserId 
    ( 
      id:"55dd69e702a488b81c4dd8ed" 

     )  
     {
        title 
        description
        start
        media{url}
        location{state,city}
        author{id, name}
        comments{text,created,author{id,name}}
        posts{url,mediaType,imageUrl,note,author{id,name}}
        _id
      }
    }
```

response like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "eventByUserId": {
            "title": null,
            "description": null,
            "start": null,
            "media": null,
            "location": null,
            "author": null,
            "comments": null,
            "posts": null,
            "_id": null
        }
    }
}
```

this is my EventType:

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Event',
  description: 'A event',
  fields: () => ({
       _id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The id of the event.',
    },
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The title of the event.',
    },
     description: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The description of the event.',
    },
    start: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The start date of the event.',
    },
    media:{
      type:new GraphQLList(MediaType),
      description:'List of media.',   
    },
    location:{
      type:new GraphQLList(LocationType),
      description:' The list of location. ',   
    },
    comments:{
      type:new GraphQLList(CommentType),
      description:' The list of Comments. ',   
    },
    posts:{
      type:new GraphQLList(PostType),
      description:' The list of Posts. ',   
    },
    created: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'The created at.',    
    },
    author:{
       type: AuthorType,
      description: 'The author for the event.',        
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Please show the call. Where exactly are you getting `null`?

Comment: You really shouldn't mix CommonJS and ES6 exports.

Comment: I am not using the common js only using the es6

Comment: using postman to get the response, i am calling the eventByUserId. which is like in the above Query

Comment: Can you also show the `EventType` definition?

Comment: @Mahesh: What do you think `module.exports` is?

Comment: Added the EventType above

Comment: module.exports are not mandatory. just i removed them and added new code please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation we are trying to resolve a list of data, so in eventByUserId we have to give GraphQLList as type like type:new GraphQLList(EventType) in the place of type:EventType. I am also editing my post. Thank you for your support..

Comment: could you be more precise in your answer by providing a code example please? I have the exact same problem. Thanks

Comment: @Sulliwane: Please give me your code I will check it once.

Comment: thanks Mahesh, I actually solved my problem by using mongoose "findById"!

Comment: Oh!! its ok. If any issues in GraphQL feel free to ask me.